# JMeter check different assertion on different threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Using JMeter, I want to check locking section that allow only 1 update

I'm running Thread group with 10 Threads and expect only 1 (not always the first) thread to return 0 and 9 others to return 1 
How can I assert it?

Thread group (10)
- HTTP Sampler
- - ? Assertion

**Edit**

10 is actually a dynamic property. So I need for any thread count to expect only 1 assertion to return success.

The test is to check that locking of record is working and can only update record once, even on stress/load test.

**Edit 2**

Using Critical Section Controller didn't give me exact result of failures

Comment: What is locking section?

Comment: Test locking in code which allow only once to do operation while other processes will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeeded, I save each thread in a unique id the failure count and I use `tearDown Thread Group` at the end to calculate the failures

In `Thread Group` after request check for invalid response with `If Controller`

and under it [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which mark failures flag by unique id per thread:

```
String threadNumber = String.valueOf(ctx.getThreadNum());
props.put("failures" + threadNumber, 1);
```

[JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) will failed unless **only exactly one** successful request exists

```
int numberOfFailures = 0;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    String id = "failures"+ String.valueOf(i);
    failureFlag = props.get(id);
    log.info("failureFlag=" + failureFlag);
    if (failureFlag == 1){
        numberOfFailures ++;
    }
}
if (numberOfFailures != 9) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 ways of implementing your scenario:

1. Use [AutoStop Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) available via [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)s, it has [AutoStop on Error Rate](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/#AutoStop-on-Error-Rate) feature so you will be able to stop your test if the percentage of failed samplers will be higher than 90. You can install AutoStop Listener using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Autostop]
2. Use [Taurus tool](http://gettaurus.org/) as a wrapper for your JMeter test, Taurus has [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) where you can put your logic to conditionally fail the whole test if error rate for a single page will be over 90%. Taurus will return non-zero exit code which you can use later on (i.e. to trigger build failure in continuous integration server).

Comment: I need a solution for Jmeter only. I'm using Jenkins with Jmeter and expect all Jmeter samplers to succeed