# Complex Jmeter scenario

Tags: jmeter

[image]I have a scenario which I'm having trouble to implement in Jmeter.

Scenario
Create 2 threads group.

Thread Group 1: should generate 100+ specific Ids (via a POST) and save the Ids somewhere to be used by other Threads Group.

Thread Group 2: Should be able to read the Ids created in Thread Group 1. 
The Thread can be set to 10 users, each user accessing 10 Ids from the above. For example user 1 will get the first 10 ids generated in Thread Group 1, so will user 2 and so on.

Problem:

I have managed to create Thread Group 1 which generates 100 specific Ids
I can only managed to save a single Id using the BeanShell Assertion using ${__setProperty(Id, ${Id})}.

However I am not sure how to save all those Ids in file or memory so that Thread Group 2 can access.

Also how can I set Thread Group 2 to pick the Ids (i.e. set the Number of Thread Users to 10, then the first user will pick the 10 Ids generated in Thread Group 1 and son on).

Currently I am investigating Jmeter and Gatling and see which tool is capable of solving these type of scenarios.

Thanks

Comment: Are the 2 thread groups going to run concurrently or one at a time?

Comment: one a time. basically Thread Group 2 relies on Thread Group 1, otherwise the tests will fail. So Thread Group 1 has to finish generating all 100 Ids, then Thread group 2 can start reading them. Also just to add extra complexity, Thread group 2 (should)  run in parallel, not one after another, but not that important

Comment: See similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473310/jmeter-check-different-assertion-on-different-threads

Comment: And you are extracting the IDs from the post request (thread group 1) using post processor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, choose option **Run Thread Groups consecutively** from your test plan so that thread groups start one at a time.

Assuming you are extracting the IDs from thread group 1 using post processor, add a [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of your post request (thread group 1) withe below code in code area

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("pathToYourFileDirectory/IDs.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
String Id = vars.get("ID");// ID should be the reference name of your post processor which extract the ID 


if(Id.equals("NOT_FOUND")){// NOT_FOUND is the default value for your post processor, in case the post request failed, you will not type anything into the csv file
    out.close();

}
else{
    out.write(Id);
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    out.close();


}
```

The above code will write your IDs into csv file `IDs.csv`.

Now add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element into your **second thread group** and fill in the fields as below

- Filename: `IDs.csv`
- Variable Names: Id

Now you can use Jmeter variable `${Id}` which will hold the ID value.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response. This should work, however I have a question regarding this line of code :String Id = vars.get("ID"); // Where should the "ID" be declared? I beliebve this 'ID' is the variable holding the extracted 'id' from the response? Currently I am using the JSON Extractor to extract the 'id' from the response and store it in a variable. I then reference that variable in the next thread.